# php ftp_nlist downloadable link

Tags: php, ftp

Im trying to display some files in a web page so the user can download it, i display the files correctly but the link href is not working, instead of download the file, the browser try to display the file in the browser and send :

Not Found

The requested URL /public_html/Factura.pdf was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

```
$connect = ftp_connect("xxx.org");
$result = ftp_login($connect, "xxx", "xxx");
$a = ftp_nlist($connect, "./public_html/");
foreach($a as $value){
echo '<a href="'.$value.'">'.basename($value).'</a> <BR>';
}
```

how can i accomplish that?
thanks!

Comment: Could you provide a var_dump() of $value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [basename()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) function on the path, this will give you the filename:

```
foreach($a as $value){
echo '<a href="'.basename($value).'">'.basename($value).'</a> <BR>';
}
```

**Edit:**
If the files are local it would be faster to just [glob()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) or [opendir()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.opendir.php) the directory, im assuming your goal is to use this script on a remote server so I would also suggest you include the url to the hosting server.

```
$server="xxx.org";
$connect = ftp_connect($server);
$result = ftp_login($connect, "xxx", "xxx");
$a = ftp_nlist($connect, "./public_html/");
foreach($a as $value){
echo '<a href="http://'.$server.'/'.basename($value).'">'.basename($value).'</a> <BR>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The public_html/ directory is not viewable outside of ftp, that's your root folder. You need to strip that out of the link the same way you have when displaying the file name, with `basename()`.

```
echo '<a href="'.basename($value).'">'.basename($value).'</a> <BR>';
```